# Cannot figure out where to add IsDBNull vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I keep getting this error:

> Additional information: Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and string

I've tried adding the IsDBNull Check to the code and cannot get it to work. Here is my code without my attmept at adding IsDBNull:

```
If EquationVariable = "=" Then  
        For Each R0w In Sorter.DataGridView1.Rows 
            Dim ColumnName As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
            Sorter.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Sorter.DataGridView1.Item(ColumnName, R0w.index)
                If Sorter.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = SearchVariable Then
                    Sorter.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
                Else
                End If
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & " Doest not = " & SearchVariable)
    End If
```

It is on this line that I am getting the error:

```
If PostalSorter.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = SearchVariable Then
```

Here is how i tried to fix it:

```
 If IsDBNull(PostalSorter.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value) Then
            Else
                If PostalSorter.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = SearchVariable Then

                    PostalSorter.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
                Else

                End If
            End If
```

Comment: if the current cell value is DBNull, you cannot compare it to something.  Show how you tried to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
If Not IsDBNull(Sorter.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value) AndAlso Sorter.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = SearchVariable Then
      Sorter.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
```

The `AndAlso` operator is handy in this instance because, unlike a regular `And`, if it comes across a condition that evaluates to `false`, it does not read any further. By making our first condition `Not isDBNull` and using an `AndAlso`, we ensure that the issue-causing comparison only occurs if in fact the `CurrentCell.Value` is not DBNull.